# Load Testing with Selenium? What are the alternatives for my situation

Tags: selenium, load-testing

Currently I'm trying to run a load test which walks through a uniquely created URL. I know JMeter is often used for load testing, but I was specifically asked to do it through something like Selenium that uses real browsers to create the URL then open that URL and complete the steps within the URL. I have created a Selenium script that can easily do this, but I need to do this 100 times concurrently and can't find a good way to do.
Is there a way to do this? I've looked into Selenium Grid but I'm not sure if I even have enough nodes to run 100 browsers concurrently. Please if you have recommendations for software or a different method of doing this I would love to hear it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can be integrated with Selenium using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) so you can re-use your code and rely on JMeter's multithreading capabilities.

If one machine won't be powerful enough to kick off 100 browsers - you can consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

In general be aware that browsers don't do any magic, they just send [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), wait for responses and render them. JMeter is not capable only of rendering the page, but if you need to load test the backend - it can mimic browser's network footprint with 100% accuracy, just make sure to [configure JMeter accordingly in order to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

JavaScript execution time and page rendering speed can be checked either using single WebDriver Sampler or a separate solution like [Lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

BrowserUp can run Selenium scripts for load testing. Watch the video on the homepage.

https://browserup.com/